# Are there any established EOS Token Standards?

Tags: tokens, token-standard

Will EOS adopt the Ethereum's ERC20 (and other token standards) or will there be a modifications since much of the development is in C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `eosio.token` contract implements what will become the standard. In the future `eosio.token` will allow users to create their own tokens that it manages.